# How can I get the faceIdlist from a vtkPolyhedron object in python?

Tags: python, c++, vtk

I'm a learner of vtk, I want to use vtkpolyhedron object to describe an irregular polyhedron, then write it into .vtu file. It has an error when I write it into unstructured grid. I use a cube as example, here is my code

```
# create a cube polyhedron
polyhedron = vtkPolyhedron()
for i in range(8):
    polyhedron.GetPointIds().InsertNextId(i)
polyhedron.Initialize()
polyhedron.GetPoints().InsertNextPoint(0, 0, 0)
polyhedron.GetPoints().InsertNextPoint(1, 0, 0)
polyhedron.GetPoints().InsertNextPoint(1, 1, 0)
polyhedron.GetPoints().InsertNextPoint(0, 1, 0)
polyhedron.GetPoints().InsertNextPoint(0, 0, 1)
polyhedron.GetPoints().InsertNextPoint(1, 0, 1)
polyhedron.GetPoints().InsertNextPoint(1, 1, 1)
polyhedron.GetPoints().InsertNextPoint(0, 1, 1)
face_1 = [6,
          4, 0, 3, 2, 1,
          4, 0, 4, 7, 3,
          4, 4, 5, 6, 7,
          4, 5, 1, 2, 6,
          4, 0, 1, 5, 4,
          4, 2, 3, 7, 6]
polyhedron.SetFaces(face_1)

# write into unstructured grid
polyGrid = vtkUnstructuredGrid()
polyGrid.InsertNextCell(polyhedron.GetCellType(), polyhedron.GetFaces())
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/science/NMM/python-NMM/script/3D_script/vtk_study/011_convert_unstructured_grid_to_polydata.py", line 145, in <module>
    polyGrid.InsertNextCell(polyhedron.GetCellType(), polyhedron.GetFaces())
TypeError: InsertNextCell argument %Id: %V
```

Then I try to print the polyhedron.getfaces

```
print(polyhedron.GetFaces())
print(type(polyhedron.GetFaces()))
```

I get

```
_0000013b5aca1e00_p_void
<class 'str'>
```

The document of vtkpolyhedron show it should return a vtkIdList https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyhedron.html#a070ddbec07089276d5f4286b975c830d

Is there any error in the use process?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `Initialize` after `SetFaces` (at least before further access to the cell)

See this similar [example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/GeometricObjects/Dodecahedron/)

In found from this [doc](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCell.html#abe88e00ff25f92dc6d2b53b4a0e60ada)

### Edit

As `GetFaces` does not seem to work as expected in python I advise to create your data following the pattern of this other [example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/GeometricObjects/Polyhedron/):

- create a `vtkPoints`, add it to the `vtkUnstructuredGrid`
- create a `vtkIdList` to list the point ids for each face
- Add the polyhedron cell to the grid: `ugrid.InsertNextCell(VTK_POLYHEDRON, cellIdList)`

Comment: thank you for your help. I modify my code 
`polyhedron.SetFaces(face_1)
polyhedron.Initialize() 
print(polyhedron.GetFaces())
print(type(polyhedron.GetFaces()))` 
the output is still 
`_00000252f5c38e20_p_void
<class 'str'>` 
By the way, I try the example and print it 
`aDodecahedron.SetFaces(faces)
aDodecahedron.Initialize()
print(aDodecahedron.GetFaces())` 
It also `_00000151d7a76580_p_void` Is this function implement in Python? Best wishes!